# Fantasy comic with a king getting impaled and topless women

Tags: story-identification, comics, medieval

In the early 2000s I read a comic in a thrift store that I wish I could identify. The name of the comic or at least a chapter in it was called something like "the trouble with dames." It featured a king getting impaled through the chest with a massive post. After his death, dozens of topless women came rushing down a mountain to a lake to mourn his death. I believe there was actual topless female nudity and it was in color.

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your question if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)

Comment: What language did you read the comic in? Was it a stapled book, a trade paperback, a European style comic album or something else? What did the cover look like? Was the drawing style Western or Asian? Any additional information would help.

Comment: sounds like it could be an issue of *Heavy Metal* There is also a series called *Monsters and Dames*.